# Read from binary file with Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I use this piece of code:

```
from struct import Struct

import struct

def read_chunk(fmt, fileobj):

    chunk_struct = Struct(fmt)
    chunk = fileobj.read(chunk_struct.size)
    return chunk_struct.unpack(chunk)

def read_record(fileobj):
    author_id, len_author_name = read_chunk('ii', f)
    author_name, nu_of_publ = read_chunk(str(len_author_name)+'si', f) # 's' or 'c' ?
    record = {  'author_id': author_id,
                'author_name': author_name,
                'publications': [] }
    for pub in range(nu_of_publ):
        pub_id, len_pub_title = read_chunk('ii', f)
        pub_title, num_pub_auth = read_chunk(str(len_pub_title)+'si', f)
        record['publications'].append({
                'publication_id': pub_id,
                'publication_title': pub_title,
                'publication_authors': [] })
        for auth in range(num_pub_auth):
            len_pub_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)
            pub_auth_name = read_chunk(str(len_pub_auth_name)+'s', f)
            record['publications']['publication_authors'].append({'name': pub_auth_name})
        year_publ, nu_of_cit = read_chunk('ii', f)
        # Finish building your record with the remaining fields...
        for cit in range(nu_of_cit):
            cit_id, len_cit_title = read_chunk('ii', f)
            cit_title, num_cit_auth = read_chunk(str(len_cit_title)+'si', f)
        for cit_auth in range(num_cit_auth):
            len_cit_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)
            cit_auth_name = read_chunk(str(len_cit_auth_name)+'s', f)
        year_cit_publ = read_chunk('i', f)
    return record

def parse_file(filename):
    records = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                records.append(read_record(f))
            except struct.error:
                break
```

to read this file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3SYAHrxLP69NHlWc25KeXFHNVE

with this format:

[image: spec]

Inside the function read_record, it read correct variables author_id, len_author_name, author_name but the nu_of_publ and below variables  aren't read correct.

Any idea what's wrong?

When i run this piece of code:

```
author_id, len_author_name = read_chunk('LL', f)
    author_name, nu_of_publ= read_chunk(str(len_author_name)+'sL', f)
    #nu_of_publ = read_chunk('I', f)# 's' or 'c' ?
    record = {  'author_id': author_id,
                'author_name': author_name,
                'publications': [] }
    print (record, nu_of_publ)


for pub in range(nu_of_publ):
        pub_id, len_pub_title = read_chunk('LL', f)
        print (pub_id, len_pub_title)
```

i take this result:

{'author_name': b'Scott Shenker', 'author_id': 1, 'publications': []} 256
15616 1953384704

but it will print 200 instead 256, 1 instead 15616 etc.

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [mcve] *here*, not using an external link? Perhaps provide a hex dump of the data. Also, reducing the code to *just the part that fails* and giving us the results you *do* get instead would really help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format is not correct:

```
author_name, nu_of_publ = read_chunk(str(len_author_name)+'si', f)
```

You are defining a structure of N characters and an integer. Those structures are [aligned](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), the same way as they would if you had the structure defined in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
struct {
    char author_name[N];
    int nu_of_publ;
};
```

What alignment does is: it puts beginning of every int to a position which is a multiple of 4. This is done (in C) because CPUs are optimized for accessing such addresses.

So, if author's name's length is 6, the next two bytes will be skipped before reading the next integer.

One solution to separate the structures:

```
author_name = read_chunk(str(len_author_name)+'s', f)
nu_of_publ, = read_chunk('i', f)
```

**Note:** The comma after nu_of_publ (`nu_of_publ,`) is to unpack the tuple returned by `read_chunk`.

Another solution is to specify structure with `=` at the beginning, based on the [table from spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

```
author_name, nu_of_publ = read_chunk('={}si'.format(len_author_name), f)
```

Comment: At the same code i have a similar problem:                                           for auth in range(num_pub_auth):
            len_pub_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)
            print (len_pub_auth_name)
            pub_auth_name = read_chunk(str(len_pub_auth_name)+'s', f)
            print (pub_auth_name)
            record['publications']['publication_authors'].append({'name': pub_auth_name})                                                                                      Printed only the len_pub_auth -(8,0) in this format- and didn't print the pub_auth_name

Comment: @lefbar `len_pub_auth_name, = read_chunk('i', f)` (note the comma!) or `len_pub_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)[0]` - because `read_chunk` returns a tuple even if there is only one item in it.

Comment: @lefbar Also, you can see that every time there is a string in this file, it is saved as length (int) followed by characters. You could have a function which reads that kind of string and use it wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice it.  At this line record['publications']['publication_authors'].append({'name': pub_auth_name}) give me this  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Which index is wrong?

Comment: @lefbar `record['publications']` is a list. It has many dictionaries inside and each of them has `['publication_authors']`.